# Ruby Savon: setting bind IP

Tags: ruby, savon

I want set bind IP for Savon-client requests. I cannot find any info about this in docs.

Savon use HTTPI for HTTP requests, but HTTPI doesn’t support setting for bind IP.

How this problem can be solved?

I use code like this:

```
require 'savon'
require 'securerandom'

realm = Base64.strict_encode64("login:pass")
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: 'https://domain.com/file.wsdl', 
  ssl_verify_mode: :none, 
  soap_header: { 'Authorization:' => "Basic #{realm}"},
  log: true
)

client.call(:foo)
```

So I want add an option like

```
bind_ip: '1.2.3.4'
```

But it’s not supported by Savon from box. May be I have to override something...

Comment: *Some* code as to how you're trying to achieve this would be extremely helpful.